# Complex integral $\int{z^n\overline{z^m}}\,dz\,d\overline{z}$ over $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $D=\{z\in\Bbb{C}, |z|<1\}$ and $P_n:D\rightarrow\Bbb{C}$ such that $P_n=\sqrt{n+1\over{\pi}}z^n$. I need to show $\{P_n: n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal system in $L^2(D)$.

$\langle P_n,P_m\rangle = \int_D P_n(z)\overline{P_m(z)}\,dz\,d\bar{z}$ on $L^2(D)$.

So $\langle P_n,P_m\rangle = 1$ if $n=m$ and $\langle P_n,P_m\rangle = 0$ if $n\neq m$.

I am having some problems with the calculation of $\int z^n\overline{z^m}\,dz\,d\bar{z}$ over $|z|<1$.

Could you help me with this problem please?

Comment: Change to polar coordinates.

Comment: How do you integrate $z^n\bar{z}^m$ over the region $D$?  I mean this makes no sense: $\int_D\,z^n\bar{z}^m\,\text{d}z$.  Did you want to say $$\iint_D\,z^n\bar{z}^m\,\text{d}z\,\text{d}\bar{z}\,?$$